# Loading dynamic content into a DIV via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, dynamic

I have a DIV that is getting its content on success of an ajax data load call:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/load.php',
    success: function(msg) { 
            document.getElementById('DIV').innerHTML = msg;
    ...
```

Within the newly loaded content, there are objects.  Therefore, I cannot instantiate those objects when the page originally loads, since they don't yet exist.  Therefore, I instantiate them on ajax success:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/load.php',
    success: function(msg) { 
            document.getElementById('DIV').innerHTML = msg;
            $("#button").button();
            $("#dp").datepicker();
            etc.
    }
```

This works fine.  However, I'm wondering if this is good practice.  First of all, every time a user triggers the function to load the DIV, I assume that all of that content needs to get added over and over again to the browser's object model.  As well, all of those jQuery instantiation calls need to get run over and over again.

Can you let me know if this is best practice, and if there is a better way of loading content into the DIV?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I know of to instantiate widgets on dynamically-added elements, unless a particular widget library provides something better. Event handlers can be bound earlier using delegation with `.on()`, but widgets normally require access to the element at instantiation time (they often modify the DOM as part of their initialization).

Answer (score 0):

The concept is fine, but there are cleaner ways. For one, you can clean up your existing code by simply consolidating the success into a single function and breaking it out of the .ajax block.

I think what you are really looking for is [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) which has recently been updated with jQuery 1.8. It will fire when ANY ajax request completes, but you can pass data that you can use to differentiate between which ajax request fires which code inside the .ajaxComplete. Quoted from docs, "the event object, the XMLHttpRequest object, and the settings object that was used in the creation of the request" can all be passed into the .ajaxComplete handler.

An example of putting this method to use (also from docs):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    if ( settings.url === "ajax/test.html" ) {
        $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " +
            xhr.responseHTML );
    }
});
```

Another option is the explicit use of deferred objects. Check out always, done, and fail especially. [Documentation here.](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)